# POST Request for ACF plugin is not working

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to publish a post in **WP** using rest api. I need some extra field too. So I have installed **ACF** plugin to insert extra field. After sending the request it returning **201** (post is created) but extra field value remaining empty(not updating).

```
                data = {
                    "title": (data['title']),
                    "content": (data['full_content']),
                    "author": 1,
                    "status": "draft",
                    "featured_media": get_image_id,
                    "acf" : {
                            "intro": "another try"
                    }
                    
                }
                response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=post_data)
```

Here `intro` is my custom field. In ACF plugin REST API option is True and in get request `acf` values showing empty value.So how can I insert extra field value?

Answer (score 1):

In your request above, try to use `"fields"`, instead of `"acf"`. See more in [this comment](https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api/issues/196#issuecomment-470779570).